# when return type is auto&& in C++14

Tags: c++14

[image: 1]

```
template <class T>
auto &&f(T &&param) {
    return param;
}

auto test() {
    int a = 1;
    cout << (f(1) = a) << endl;
    cout << (f(1) = 2) << endl;
}
```

I cannot understand why the return type of f(1) is int&, and why f(1) can be assigned to both left value and right value

Comment: A named variable is an lvalue, even if its type is rvalue reference. "**[expr.prim.id.unqual]/2** The result [of an *id-expression*] is the entity denoted by the identifier... The expression is an lvalue if the entity is a ... variable...". This is why `auto&&` is deduced to `int&`. The function returns a reference to a temporary initialized from the literal `1` and bound to `param`. That reference is good until the end of the full expression; in other words, until the semicolon.

Comment: please do not use code images better is to write is as text